# gulp clean is not working in correct manner

Tags: node.js, gulp, del

I have directory structure like this.

```
dist
|--client
   |--assets
      |--images
   |--bower_components
|--server
|--.bower.json
```

I am trying to clean dist folder, except assets/images folder.

But when i execute this command in dryRun mode, it doesn't remove assets/images file. But after disabling it, it remove all the files and folder.

```
gulp.task('clean:dist', () => {
   del.sync([
    `${paths.dist}/!(.git*|.openshift|Procfile)**`,
     `${paths.dist}/client/**`,
    `!${paths.dist}/client/assets`,
    `!${paths.dist}/client/assets/**`], {
    //dryRun: true
  });
  //console.log('dELETE FIELSE ARE: ' + JSON.stringify(value));
});
```

value of used constant is:

```
${paths.dist} ='dist';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [offical `del` documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/del#beware) states the following:

> The glob pattern `**` matches all children and the parent.
>
> So this won't work:
>
> ```
> del.sync(['public/assets/**', '!public/assets/goat.png']);
> ```
>
> You have to explicitly ignore the parent directories too:
>
> ```
> del.sync(['public/assets/**', '!public/assets', '!public/assets/goat.png']);
> ```

In your case you delete `dist/client/**`, which includes the `dist/client` directory itself. If you just ignore `dist/client/assets/**` the `dist/client` directory is still deleted.

You need to explicitly ignore the `dist/client` directory:

```
gulp.task('clean:dist', () => {
   del.sync([
    `${paths.dist}/!(.git*|.openshift|Procfile)**`,
    `${paths.dist}/client/**`,
    `!${paths.dist}/client`,
    `!${paths.dist}/client/assets/**`]);
});
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks :)